# Async Page Navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, uwp

Not really a serious issue, but like the title states I'm looking to essentially navigate between pages using a `NavigationView` with pages that can load asynchronously or be cancelled.  Currently, when I select a `NavigationViewItem` to navigate to the specified page, the entire application locks until that page is loaded.

The goal is to not have the main shell's UI lock while a page is loading.  Also, the user should be able to select a page and then select a different page before the first selection loads, therefore cancelling the first selection and then loading the new page.

I'm somewhat familiar with async `Task` and cancellation tokens, but I'm not sure how to actually implement this due to the thread restrictions that apply to async functions that impact the UI.  I also took a look at `IAsyncOperation` (like in a `ContentDialog`) and `IAsyncAction`, but couldn't really find any examples similar to this scenario.

Any insight you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't load the actual UI elements on a background thread. What is causing the delay in your case? The view model may load data on a background thread.

Comment: The load times for most pages is usually only a few seconds (on initialization) and I do have some data being loaded via the VM.  Really the issue is the locking up of the UI on initial selection of a page.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of this "initial selection" then.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would illustrate an example really.  As I understand it, the first time a page is loaded within a frame control, all of it's UI elements and VM data have to be loaded from scratch.  But after this 'initial' loading, the page gets cached in the frame and doesn't have to be reloaded.

Comment: Please share a sample which could reproduce this behavior. It's hard to tell what will be the reason without knowing anything about your real scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You are not possible to cancel the navigation as task because it not a Asynchronous methods.

The better way is not to load all the controls or data in the page when you just navigated to the page. You could only load the necessary information and load other information when it is required.